# css grid vs flexbox : why does css grid cause repaints and flexbox not

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I like very much css grid because of its simplicity. But there seems to be a performance issue with css grid that flexbox does not have.

I have implemented a two column full screen page both columns having a form with input box and a list of items with overflow-y:auto. One example where the left and right panel are implemented using flexbox and one where left and right panel are implemented with css grid.

this is the flexbox version : https://web-platform-wtfgmj.stackblitz.io/

and this is the css grid version : https://web-platform-wtfgmj.stackblitz.io/index2.html

Open the developper tools in chrome and enable paint flashing (tools/rendering has to be enabled).
When typing in one of the input boxes, the css grid version will repaint all items in the list. The flexbox version does not have this problem.

I would like to understand why css grid repaints all items in the list when typing in the input box ? And can it somehow be avoided ?

Update : Seems to be problem with stackblitz...
included as code snippets

**Update 2: because it's little bit burried in comments:**
So I filed a bug report with chrome (bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1204446, upon suggestion of dgrogan) and they seem to confirm that it is a performance issue with chrome's current grid implementation. Apparently they are busy with a new implementation LayoutNGGrid which would solve the issue

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: none;
}
my-app {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 7fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1em;
  gap: 0.6em;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 1em;
}

.itemspanel {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.itemheader {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.items {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 0;
}

.itemrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.itemrow > span:nth-child(1) {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.itemrow > span:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.itemrowgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  padding: 0 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
}

.panels {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "left right" 1fr
    / 1fr 2fr;
  gap: 1em;
  min-height: 0;
}
.panelleft {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  grid-area: left;
  min-height: 0;
}
.panelright {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  grid-area: right;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app ng-version="11.0.8">
    <div class="panels">
      <div class="panelleft">
        <form novalidate="" name="frmFilters" autocomplete="off" class="header ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty">
          <label >Search:</label><input  type="text" name="name" ng-reflect-name="name" ng-reflect-model="00000" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty"><label ></label><button  type="button">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div class="itemspanel">
          <div class="itemheader"></div>
          <div class="items">
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Joelynn</span><span >Hitzmann</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Farris</span><span >Espine</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Linnet</span><span >Nare</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Heidie</span><span >Coolican</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ulrike</span><span >Lowndsborough</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Claudine</span><span >Caneo</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Janella</span><span >Thurborn</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Menard</span><span >Wolledge</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Alasteir</span><span >Annandale</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Isabelita</span><span >Byrom</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jim</span><span >Issard</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mic</span><span >Tiddeman</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Carce</span><span >McClunaghan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Archibaldo</span><span >Jacqueme</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sybilla</span><span >Vivyan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Herve</span><span >Lund</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Wade</span><span >Calway</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Irita</span><span >Newvell</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Lucie</span><span >Hurrion</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sherie</span><span >Bapty</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Estella</span><span >Lettington</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Lion</span><span >Ganforthe</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Siouxie</span><span >January 1st</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Clay</span><span >Knightsbridge</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Shir</span><span >Desesquelle</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Magda</span><span >Brew</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Didi</span><span >Scanlon</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Petr</span><span >Clerk</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Frazier</span><span >Harler</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Deonne</span><span >Scoffham</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Meggi</span><span >Klampk</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Darby</span><span >Huey</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Berna</span><span >Batram</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ashli</span><span >Ducarel</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Marilin</span><span >Gothup</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mariya</span><span >Fettis</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Anett</span><span >Stookes</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Adella</span><span >Wash</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ricky</span><span >Pellamonuten</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Nora</span><span >Hourigan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Pancho</span><span >Wynn</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Magdaia</span><span >Walthall</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Thatch</span><span >Llorente</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Margaretta</span><span >Ramiro</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jacques</span><span >Smallacombe</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Gamaliel</span><span >Learoyd</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jyoti</span><span >Sholl</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Elbertine</span><span >Larwell</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sebastian</span><span >Alvarado</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mart</span><span >Hentzeler</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panelright d2">
        <form novalidate="" name="frmFilters" autocomplete="off" class="header ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
          <label >Search:</label><input  type="text" name="name1" ng-reflect-name="name1" ng-reflect-model="0000" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched"><label ></label><button  type="button">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div class="itemspanel">
          <div class="itemheader"></div>
          <div class="items">
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Joelynn</span><span >Hitzmann</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Farris</span><span >Espine</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Linnet</span><span >Nare</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Heidie</span><span >Coolican</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ulrike</span><span >Lowndsborough</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Claudine</span><span >Caneo</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Janella</span><span >Thurborn</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Menard</span><span >Wolledge</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Alasteir</span><span >Annandale</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Isabelita</span><span >Byrom</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jim</span><span >Issard</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mic</span><span >Tiddeman</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Carce</span><span >McClunaghan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Archibaldo</span><span >Jacqueme</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sybilla</span><span >Vivyan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Herve</span><span >Lund</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Wade</span><span >Calway</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Irita</span><span >Newvell</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Lucie</span><span >Hurrion</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sherie</span><span >Bapty</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Estella</span><span >Lettington</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Lion</span><span >Ganforthe</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Siouxie</span><span >January 1st</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Clay</span><span >Knightsbridge</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Shir</span><span >Desesquelle</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Magda</span><span >Brew</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Didi</span><span >Scanlon</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Petr</span><span >Clerk</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Frazier</span><span >Harler</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Deonne</span><span >Scoffham</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Meggi</span><span >Klampk</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Darby</span><span >Huey</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Berna</span><span >Batram</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ashli</span><span >Ducarel</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Marilin</span><span >Gothup</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mariya</span><span >Fettis</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Anett</span><span >Stookes</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Adella</span><span >Wash</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ricky</span><span >Pellamonuten</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Nora</span><span >Hourigan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Pancho</span><span >Wynn</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Magdaia</span><span >Walthall</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Thatch</span><span >Llorente</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Margaretta</span><span >Ramiro</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jacques</span><span >Smallacombe</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Gamaliel</span><span >Learoyd</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jyoti</span><span >Sholl</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Elbertine</span><span >Larwell</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sebastian</span><span >Alvarado</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mart</span><span >Hentzeler</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: none;
}



my-app {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 7fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1em;
  gap: 0.6em;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 1em;
}

.itemspanel {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.itemheader {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.items {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 0;
}

.itemrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.itemrow > span:nth-child(1) {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.itemrow > span:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.itemrowgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  padding: 0 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
}

.panels {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  min-height: 0;
}
.panelleft,
.panelright {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.panelleft {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.panelright {
  flex: 1 1 200%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app ng-version="11.0.8">
    <div class="panels">
      <div class="panelleft">
        <form novalidate="" name="frmFilters" autocomplete="off" class="header ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty">
          <label >Search:</label><input  type="text" name="name" ng-reflect-name="name" ng-reflect-model="00000" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty"><label ></label><button  type="button">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div class="itemspanel">
          <div class="itemheader"></div>
          <div class="items">
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Joelynn</span><span >Hitzmann</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Farris</span><span >Espine</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Linnet</span><span >Nare</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Heidie</span><span >Coolican</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ulrike</span><span >Lowndsborough</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Claudine</span><span >Caneo</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Janella</span><span >Thurborn</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Menard</span><span >Wolledge</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Alasteir</span><span >Annandale</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Isabelita</span><span >Byrom</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jim</span><span >Issard</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mic</span><span >Tiddeman</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Carce</span><span >McClunaghan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Archibaldo</span><span >Jacqueme</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sybilla</span><span >Vivyan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Herve</span><span >Lund</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Wade</span><span >Calway</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Irita</span><span >Newvell</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Lucie</span><span >Hurrion</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sherie</span><span >Bapty</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Estella</span><span >Lettington</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Lion</span><span >Ganforthe</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Siouxie</span><span >January 1st</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Clay</span><span >Knightsbridge</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Shir</span><span >Desesquelle</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Magda</span><span >Brew</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Didi</span><span >Scanlon</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Petr</span><span >Clerk</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Frazier</span><span >Harler</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Deonne</span><span >Scoffham</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Meggi</span><span >Klampk</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Darby</span><span >Huey</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Berna</span><span >Batram</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ashli</span><span >Ducarel</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Marilin</span><span >Gothup</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mariya</span><span >Fettis</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Anett</span><span >Stookes</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Adella</span><span >Wash</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ricky</span><span >Pellamonuten</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Nora</span><span >Hourigan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Pancho</span><span >Wynn</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Magdaia</span><span >Walthall</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Thatch</span><span >Llorente</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Margaretta</span><span >Ramiro</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jacques</span><span >Smallacombe</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Gamaliel</span><span >Learoyd</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jyoti</span><span >Sholl</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Elbertine</span><span >Larwell</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sebastian</span><span >Alvarado</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mart</span><span >Hentzeler</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panelright d2">
        <form novalidate="" name="frmFilters" autocomplete="off" class="header ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
          <label >Search:</label><input  type="text" name="name1" ng-reflect-name="name1" ng-reflect-model="0000" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched"><label ></label><button  type="button">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div class="itemspanel">
          <div class="itemheader"></div>
          <div class="items">
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Joelynn</span><span >Hitzmann</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Farris</span><span >Espine</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Linnet</span><span >Nare</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Heidie</span><span >Coolican</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ulrike</span><span >Lowndsborough</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Claudine</span><span >Caneo</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Janella</span><span >Thurborn</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Menard</span><span >Wolledge</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Alasteir</span><span >Annandale</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Isabelita</span><span >Byrom</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jim</span><span >Issard</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mic</span><span >Tiddeman</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Carce</span><span >McClunaghan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Archibaldo</span><span >Jacqueme</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sybilla</span><span >Vivyan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Herve</span><span >Lund</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Wade</span><span >Calway</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Irita</span><span >Newvell</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Lucie</span><span >Hurrion</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sherie</span><span >Bapty</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Estella</span><span >Lettington</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Lion</span><span >Ganforthe</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Siouxie</span><span >January 1st</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Clay</span><span >Knightsbridge</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Shir</span><span >Desesquelle</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Magda</span><span >Brew</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Didi</span><span >Scanlon</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Petr</span><span >Clerk</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Frazier</span><span >Harler</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Deonne</span><span >Scoffham</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Meggi</span><span >Klampk</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Darby</span><span >Huey</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Berna</span><span >Batram</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ashli</span><span >Ducarel</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Marilin</span><span >Gothup</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mariya</span><span >Fettis</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Anett</span><span >Stookes</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Adella</span><span >Wash</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Ricky</span><span >Pellamonuten</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Nora</span><span >Hourigan</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Pancho</span><span >Wynn</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Magdaia</span><span >Walthall</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Thatch</span><span >Llorente</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Margaretta</span><span >Ramiro</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jacques</span><span >Smallacombe</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Gamaliel</span><span >Learoyd</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Jyoti</span><span >Sholl</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Elbertine</span><span >Larwell</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Sebastian</span><span >Alvarado</span></div>
            <div class="itemrowgrid"><span >Mart</span><span >Hentzeler</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't open the links. please create a jsfiddle or codepen example

Comment: FWIW, the links open, but never load. Additionally, you need to post (or link to) actual code to get help.

Comment: I did like you mentioned but it seems that nothing is repainted. Which chrome version are you using? Mine is 90.0...

Comment: I use chrome 90 as well, however I noticed chrome does not show paint flashing inside iframes and full screen display of stackoverflow snippets still embeds the content in an iframe. (You can see that paint flashing in iframe does not work because otherwise when you type in input box, at least the input box would show paint flashes and it does not). You could save the html of the iframe locally and view it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the problem locally (almost at least). As you can see in the following image, in my browser (Chromium v92.0.4488.0) only an area on the far right of the column is repainted - exactly the area where the scrollbar will be displayed when it is used.

[image]

Using Firefox (v88.0) or Safari (v14.0.3), on the other hand, neither in the Flexbox nor the grid example anything other than the input is being repainted.

Since you don't use absolute values for the height of the containers, I suspect it happens due to the calculation of the height and whether the scrollbar needs to be displayed. Chrome seems to behave differently here than other browsers.

A simple fix seems to be to define an absolute height for the containers (vh, although it's a [relative unit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), seems to work too):

```css
.panelleft,
.panelright {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, adding above classes seems to fix it (fully,in my case when I download first example local all items in rows show paint flash, be sure to download frame source not html source in order to see fully). Not perfect though, suppose there is something before the panels (eg. full with header ) then 100vh breaks the page (overflows)

Comment: Yes, that's true. In such a case, you can either use fixed values for the height of the header and the containers (e.g. `.panelleft,.panelright { height: 95vh; } header { height: 5vh; }` or `.panelleft,.panelright { height: calc(100vh - 50px); } header { height: 50px; }`), or alternatively calculate the remaining space via JS and apply that to the panels.

Comment: However with flexbox alone this is not necessary, it works without applying heights . and thus is more flexible

Comment: I agree. As my tests have shown, it does work without repainting in Firefox and Safari. Let's hope that Chrome will do the same soon.

Comment: I don't really follow the evolution of this problem and discussion. But could you file a bug at https://crbug.com/new with a minimal case that demonstrates chrome flexbox repainting but the other browsers don't?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1204446

Comment: @rekna Thanks. And sorry that I misunderstood: I thought flexbox was having the repaint problem, not grid. Now that I see that it's grid, that makes more sense. Flexbox got a huge makeover last year. This year it's grid turn for the improvements.